# EF Code First Not Generating Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working on an EF Code first site, and I've written my classes and a context class, the source of which is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;
using MySite.SalesTool.Data.Entities;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;


namespace MySite.SalesTool.Data
{
    public class SalesToolEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JobAssigner> JobAssigners { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JobFile> JobFiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<JobStatus> JobStatuses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AssignedUser> AssignedUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The project builds fine, but when I go to run the site, no tables are created in the database and I get an error stating that the database can't find whichever context object I try and access, presumably because the code first has not generated any of the necessary tables.

Any ideas why it wouldn't generate any of the tables at all, and not give me any kind of error information?

Comment: In web.config you should name your connection string exactly like your Context class

Comment: How do you generate the database? EF doesn't create tables alone - EF always has to create the whole database.

Comment: That actually depends. If it's SQLCe then it will create it on it's own

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008 R2. I'm using an empty database. I updated the DbContext to have the line of code: `public SalesToolEntities() : base("SalesTool") {}` and it doesn't throw the dbo objects error, however, no tables get generated (even if I call the Database.Create() method of the context). I can add objects to the context, but they don't get persisted, as there's no DB table.

Comment: @Tim: Try to call `Database.Delete()` first.

Comment: As a sanity check, it might be worth checking that your database instance is located at whatever your connection string is saying it is at. E.g. mine says `.\SQLEXPRESS` and it creates a database and all the tables automagically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have an initialization strategy?

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SalesToolEntities>());
```

From what you subscribe it sounds like you've created the database yourself. Then you need to specify an initialization 
strategy otherwise no tables/data will be added to the database and querying the database will result in an exception: {"The specified table does not exist. [ sometable ]"}

Comment: Does this line have to be included in the global.asax file or the initializer file that is trying to create new tables with test data? im using EF6 and trying to create a couple of tables with some test data in it, the database is being created but none of that tables are.

Comment: In global.asax. And you should submit a new question instead of submitting an answer with a question in it: you'll get quicker anwers that way.

Comment: Thanks Steven K. I figured it out, lol. I see people post repeated version of this question all the time, so i figured i'd piggy back on this one. Probably would of got response days ago if i just posted separate question.